# Why can't I plot image histogram's in python-OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, histogram

I have to get a image, apply Histogram equalization and plot the histogram of both images (original and modified). So I tried this code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, img_as_float, img_as_ubyte
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

gray = cv2.imread("folder\img1.jpg",0)


equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)

io.imshow(gray)
io.imshow(equ)

histr = cv2.calcHist([gray],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
  
plt.plot(histr)
plt.show()
```

But The plot returned is..:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: You could just use Mathplotlib histograms. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_histograms.asp and https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwivi5zX47PxAhVJoZ4KHd0QAU8QFjAAegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmatplotlib.org%2Fstable%2Fapi%2F_as_gen%2Fmatplotlib.pyplot.hist.html&usg=AOvVaw0V-aXyEyA-B8soLZBTi57L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a new figure, so the histogram is plotted on the last figure that displays the image.
You may create a new figure before plotting the histogram:

```
histr = cv2.calcHist(gray, [0], None, [256], (0,255))

plt.figure() # Create new figure for the histogram plot
plt.plot(histr)
plt.show()
```